# gqlgen: Unwanted Resolver is generated

Tags: go, graphql, gqlgen, go-generate

I'm using `gqlgen`, and I'd like to add a new method to the Query resolver. The added method looks something like this:

```
type Query {
...
Foo(bar: Int!): Foo
...
}
```

The type for `Foo` is already declared in the file and is being mapped properly to a model in a `.go` file (I know this because of previous methods that use the type). When I try to generate code from the above addition, a new `FooResolver` is added to the `ResolverRoot`.

Any ideas why this is the case?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having a similar issue now with multiple resolvers being generated.